# Bakckground Image Position "Flickering" & "Jumping" when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, background

I seem to have a problem using background images that have a 'position' set on them in Firefox (and also on iOS).

On iOS, when you scroll the images disappear for a second, then come back. On Firefox, they only disappear when I use the .animate() method to navigate down the page.

Has anybody come across a problem similar to this?

I'm using sprites, and the positions are set to (for example) '20px 400px' but then when I scroll, it's as if they are reverting back to '0px 0px' but then jumping back to the original position.

Strange!

Comment: Some code would definitely help...

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with jquery, css alone should not cause that, please include some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` ended up fixing this